# NGINX Reverse Proxy Server sending RST to upstream and FIN to downstream after 5 Minutes of inactivity

Tags: nginx, proxy, tcp, timeout, keepalive

My current nginx setup always kill the TCP connection after 5 minutes of inactivity, i.e no transaction.

I have this setup which requires TLS1.2 connection connecting from my internal network [client application] to public network [server]. It only use TCP ports (not http/https) and establish with a server located at public network. The client application does not support TLS1.2 connection hence the introduction of nginx proxy/reverse proxy for TLS wrapping purpose. You may refer below :

```
              Internal Network                 | INTERNET/Public
```

[Client Application] <-----> [NGINX Reverse Proxy] <--- | ---> [Public Server]

```
           <Non TLS TCP Traffic>            <TLS 1.2>
```

- using stream module
- no error shown in nginx error log
- access log showing TCP 200 Status but the session only last 300s everytime. [Recorded in the access_log][access_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mGb4.jpg)

Below is my nginx configuration

```
stream {
resolver 127.0.0.1;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
log_format basic '$remote_addr [$time_local] '
                 '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                 '$session_time $upstream_addr'
                 '"$upstream_bytes_sent" "$upstream_bytes_received" "$upstream_connect_time"';
access_log /var/log/nginx/stream.access.log basic;
error_log log_file;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_log;
server {
         listen 35012;
         proxy_pass X.X.X.X:35012;
         proxy_timeout 86400s;
         proxy_connect_timeout 1200s;
         proxy_socket_keepalive on;
         ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
         ssl_session_timeout 30m;
    proxy_ssl  on;
    proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/backend.crt;
    proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/certs/backend.key;
    proxy_ssl_protocols           TLSv1.2;
    proxy_ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    proxy_ssl_verify_depth  2;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
}
```

After capturing the tcp packet and check via wireshark, I found out that the nginx is sending out the RST to the public server and then send FIN/ACK (refer attached pcap picture)[wireshark_pcap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbT8s.png)

I have tried to enable keepalive related parameters as per the nginx config above and also check on the OS's TCP tunable and i could not find any related settings which make NGINX to kill the TCP connection.

Anyone encountering the same issues?

Comment: welcome to serverfault where business related question should be asked, what is the business related question or issue in here?

Comment: my nginx keep killing the TCP connection after 5 minutes of inactivity but i can't seem to find any errors in the log or anything related in my configuration.

Comment: What is the business case, that you follow up, that a connection that has been dead for five minutes requires to keep alive?